# Table saw blade keeps jamming and slowing down

Tags: table-saw, cutting, tool-maintenance

[image]I have an old Sears tablesaw.  It was my Grandfather's and it is well over 40 years old.

Please excuse me for not being the sharpest tool in the shed, but about a year ago I accidently started the blade with a piece of wood already inserted into the teeth.  The saw has never run right since.  It keeps slowing down the deeper I get into the cut.  I keep having to retract and let the blade regain its speed.  Well, today I was trying to cut a 4 food section of plywood and the saw just can't handle it.  I dug into the problem some more and here's what I came up with.

The motor turns a wheel with a belt on it.  The belt turns another wheel with a lug on it.  The blade mounts onto this lug.  Well, I noticed that the lug is turning freely of the wheel.

The problem is that I can't find how to stop the lug from turning.  I found where I believe it mounts in the back, and found a pin of some sot neat it, but am unsure if that's relevant.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  I`m not sure if it will help, but Is there a model number for the saw? Also, I would have thought there might be a key between the lug and the pulley wheel it attaches to.  Have you taken the lug off of the wheel?

Comment: In the 'back of lug' pic, is that like a cover that you can pry off?

Comment: Hi there everyone.

Comment: Hi there everyone.

Ash:  I don't know the model number or where it would be on it.  It was given to me by my Grandfather.  He had it for at least 50 years and we don't even knwo where the manual is.

I don't know how to take the lug off of the wheel.

Aloy:  AFAIK it isn't a cover.  I don't even know why there is that marking in the chassie of the motor.

Comment: Since I ran out of characotrs above:  The more I think about it, I'm not so sure this is my issue.  The blade slips over the lug and is held to the wheel by a washer that is the exact diamater as the pully and a nut over it.  If this lug were tight, it would hold the position of the nut, which would hold the position of the washer, which would hold the position of the blade, while the wheel is turned by the belt.  I think the lug is suppose to turn freely, so that the nut, washer, and blade all turn when the wheel is turned by the pully.  That said, what else shoud I be looking for?

Comment: Look for the manufacturer's plate somewhere on the saw. It will say "Sears" or "Craftsman" somewhere on it and will also have other markings, most likely stamped in, that will indicate a model number. Manuals for a _lot_ of old equipment are available on-line, and there might just be something in the manual that will include adjustment info.

Comment: @phkc070408 please [edit] your question to put your clarifications in the body of the question, not hidden in comments.

Answer (score 4):

To me it looks like you've got a stripped belt.

It's a bit hard to tell for sure from your photos but it looks very much to me like the spindle and wheel which are connected by the belt are gear-like, to accept a toothed belt, and it looks like the belt was originally toothed, but that the teeth have worn away.

Your belt should look something like this:

[image]

... but it looks like the teeth are gone. I'd take a closer look and see if you can make out if the belt should be toothed.

The belts do wear down and will particularly wear down or even just strip straight off if you overload the blade. Also the rubber they're made of will just degrade over time which will contribute to the wear. I have worked with saws which used toothed belts before so they definitely are a thing, even if not all saw drivebelts are toothed.

If you take the belt off you may be able to see some writing on the belt which will tell you what the specs of the belt are. If not, you can work out the specification with a few measurements.

Gates are a company who make the "Powergrip GT" line of belts which are a high quality belt I have used in the past. If you look on their website you can find a guide on how to specify the belts - I believe you'll need a pitch (distance between each tooth), the number of teeth on the belt (which will give you the overall length), and a width. The belts can be metric or imperial.

The guide on specification can be found within this PDF (around page 8 or 9 I think):

https://www.gates.com/content/dam/gates/home/resources/resource-library/catalogs/powergripdrivedesignmanual_17195_2014.pdf